# Can we change the network structure of Connection strategy in Nearby connections?

Tags: google-nearby

Can we choose a specific wifi channel in nearby connection api or not...?
If so how...?
Because we want to select specific channels in nearby connection for different purposes, as some channels are Congested and connection establishment between devices is slow, so, if possible we would like

1. A channel to Advertise/Discover
2. A channel to exchange the metadata files after the discovery/advertising
3. A channel to exchange files like images,videos etc

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not get access to the underlying Wifi stack used by Nearby Connections. The goal is to be a simple abstraction layer, so we purposefully avoid exposing too many knobs to tweak and turn.

I can file a bug internally to more optimally choose the Wifi channel. If you have more specifics (eg. these channels are typically congested), I can attach that to the bug as well.